# Cant Build Gradle

Tags: java, android, xml, android-gradle-plugin

I have repository that wont let me build the gradle. It builds for all the other people who have it also. Anyways I am kind of a noob so please be understanding. So I get two errors:

```
Error:Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\marshall\AndroidStudioProjects\mlg-soundboard\MLGSoundboard\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
```

And

```
Error:Content is not allowed in trailing section.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: publish your AndroidManifest,xml

Comment: Attach here the content of AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Check the closing manifest tag at the very bottom of your AndroidManifest.xml and make sure that there are no trailing letters or spaces.